# Merge arrays matching a particular key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which is like this:

```js
var arr = [{
  "date": "JAN",
  "value": 5,
  "weight": 3
}, {
  "date": "JAN",
  "value": 4,
  "weight": 23
}, {
  "date": "FEB",
  "value": 9,
  "weight": 1
}, {
  "date": "FEB",
  "value": 10,
  "weight": 30
}]
```

I want to match the primary key which is here`date`. Matching this I want to merge the rest of the key values and get this following output:

```js
[{
  "date": "JAN",
  "value": [5, 4],
  "weight": [3, 23]
}, {
  "date": "FEB",
  "value": [9, 10],
  "weight": [1, 30]
}]
```

I have written a function like this but can't figure out how to concat the key values:

```js
var arr = [{
  "date": "JAN",
  "value": 5,
  "weight": 3
}, {
  "date": "JAN",
  "value": 4,
  "weight": 23
}, {
  "date": "FEB",
  "value": 9,
  "weight": 1
}, {
  "date": "FEB",
  "value": 10,
  "weight": 30
}]

const transform = (arr, primaryKey) => {
  var newValue = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (primaryKey[i] === primaryKey[j]) {
        newValue.push({
          ...arr[i],
          ...arr[j]
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return newValue
};

console.log(transform(arr,'date'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the list while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the primary-key and the value is the grouped object. In every iteration, create/update the pair.
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), return the list of grouped objects

```js
const transform = (arr, primaryKey) => [...
  arr.reduce((map, { [primaryKey]: key, ...e }) => {
    const { [primaryKey]: k, ...props } = map.get(key) ?? {};
    for(let prop in e) {
      props[prop] = [...(props[prop] ?? []), e[prop]];
    }
    map.set(key, { [primaryKey]: key, ...props });
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

const arr = [ { "date": "JAN", "value": 5, "weight": 3 }, { "date": "JAN", "value": 4, "weight": 23 }, { "date": "FEB", "value": 9, "weight": 1 }, { "date": "FEB", "value": 10, "weight": 30 } ]; 
console.log( transform(arr, 'date') );
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
const transform = (arr, primaryKey) => {
    var newValue = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i]["value"] = [arr[i]["value"]];
        arr[i]["weight"] = [arr[i]["weight"]];
    }
    newValue.push(arr[0])
    for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        let contains = false;
        for(let j = 0; j < newValue.length; j++){
            if(newValue[j][primaryKey] == arr[i][primaryKey]){
                newValue[j]["value"].push(arr[i]["value"][0]);
                newValue[j]["weight"].push(arr[i]["weight"][0]);
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        if(!contains){
            newValue.push(arr[i]);
        }
        
    }
   return newValue
};

var arr = [{
              "date": "JAN",
              "value": 5,
              "weight": 3
          }, {
              "date": "JAN",
              "value": 4,
              "weight": 23
          }, {
              "date": "FEB",
              "value": 9,
              "weight": 1
          }, {
              "date": "FEB",
              "value": 10,
              "weight": 30
          }] 
          
var newthing = transform(arr,"date");
console.log(newthing);
```

Output:

```
[ { date: 'JAN', value: [ 5, 4 ], weight: [ 3, 23 ] },
  { date: 'FEB', value: [ 9, 10 ], weight: [ 1, 30 ] } ]
```

The way this code works is that first, we turn the values of the keys for `"value"` and `"weight"` into lists.

Then, we begin by pushing the first element of `arr` into `newValue`.

From here, we do a nested for loop to iterate through the remaining of `arr` and `newValue`:

If the value of `"date"` for every element of `arr` already exists in `newValue`, then we will push in the values of `"value"` and `"weight"` that belongs to `arr`.

However, if it does not exist, then we will simply push that element inside of `newValue`.

I hope this helped answer your question! Pleas let me know if you need any further help or clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining a couple of reduce can also do the same job:

```
const arr = [{
              "date": "JAN",
              "value": 5,
              "weight": 3
          }, {
              "date": "JAN",
              "value": 4,
              "weight": 23
          }, {
              "date": "FEB",
              "value": 9,
              "weight": 1
          }, {
              "date": "FEB",
              "value": 10,
              "weight": 30
          }] 

const arrayMappedByDate = arr.reduce((acc, curData) => {
  if (acc[curData.date]) {
    acc[curData.date].push(curData)
  } else {
    acc[curData.date] = [curData]
  }
  return acc
}, {})

const transformedArray = Object.entries(arrayMappedByDate).map(([dateInit, data]) => {
 const normalized = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   if (acc.date) {
     acc.value.push(cur.value)
     acc.weight.push(cur.weight)
   } else {
     acc = { 
       date: cur.date,
       value: [cur.value],
       weight: [cur.weight]
     }
   }
   return acc
 }, {})
 return { [dateInit]: normalized }
})


 console.log(transformedArray)
```